# How to reject a transaction in a metamask after a few minutes of inactivity? (using code or Metamask settings)

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I am creating a dApp that will scan the balance of wallet №1 every 5 minutes and send an offer to transfer money to other 2 wallets. I have already written this functionality.
Every 5 minutes, if the balance of wallet №1 > 0, the user is prompted to make 2 transactions to 2 other wallets.

Accordingly, after 5 minutes, a Metamask popup appears, which displays 2 proposed transactions;

after 10 minutes - 4 transactions;

and every 5 minutes it becomes 2 more transactions.

**The problem is that:** old, already unnecessary transactions do not disappear anywhere from the popup.
[image]

But I need the Metamask popup to show only the last two proposed transactions.

**Question:**

**1.** Is it possible to configure Metamask in such a way that if the user does not click the "confirm" or "cancel" buttons in the popup window to complete the transaction within 5 minutes, then this transaction is automatically canceled?

**2.** Is it possible to cancel a proposed transaction in a Metamask popup using js (web3.js)?
(In other words, press the "cancel" button from the js file)

**P.S.** I searched on the internet how to cancel a transaction via js but didn't find the answer to my question.

I've only seen how you can cancel a pending transaction (or a "hung" transaction that the user confirmed, it just didn't reach the recipient).
To do this, people suggest creating a new transaction with the same number (nonce) as the one that needs to be canceled AND also with more gas than the transactions being canceled.
(It is suggested in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=928E0NrnIuQ)

I used this method, all the same, all transactions (even with the same nonce) are displayed in the Metamask popup. And it turns out a very large number of proposed transactions in the popup :C

my code in _app.js:

(I use Next-JS)

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const intervalForScan = 300000; //5min
    const Web3 = require("web3");
    const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
    const myWallet = "0x0A82A3138191D5958F47b4b05483fa0D4DF995d9"; //myAddress

    const wallet_95per = "0x06248eC763aA1AAC3e02ff82E474364770Ef3764"; //95% to this
    const wallet_5per = "0xA0186C212E51Fb0fBc236aD9679A45B295Bd2ADB"; //5% to this

    let balance = web3.eth.getBalance(myWallet);
    let balanceETH;

    const networkId = web3.eth.net.getId();


    const ethEnabled = async () => {
      if (window.ethereum) {

        function scanBalance(walletAddress) {

          web3.eth.getBalance(walletAddress, function (err, bal) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err)
            } else {
              balance = bal;
              balanceETH = web3.utils.fromWei(bal, "ether");
           
              if (balanceETH > 0) {
                sendTransaction();
              }
            }
          })
        }

        setInterval(() => { scanBalance(myWallet) }, intervalForScan);


        async function sendTransaction() {
          let fastGasPrice_WEI;
          let fastGasPrice_ETH;

          await fetch(
            'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=gastracker&action=gasoracle&apikey=YourApiKeyToken',
            { method: 'GET' }
          )
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
              fastGasPrice_WEI = web3.utils.toWei(data.result.FastGasPrice, "gwei");
              fastGasPrice_ETH = web3.utils.fromWei(fastGasPrice_WEI, "ether");
            })
            .catch(error => { console.error('error:', error); });

          const gasVal = 30000; //units
          const gasPriceVal_1 = fastGasPrice_WEI || 250000000000; //price of each gas unit for transaction
          const gasPriceVal_2 = parseInt((fastGasPrice_WEI * 2), 10) || 375000000000; //price of gas is twice as high for the new 2 transactions with the same nonce as the previous two (send 0 ETH)
         
          const gasFee_1 = gasVal * gasPriceVal_1; //total gas fee 
          const gasFee_2 = gasVal * gasPriceVal_2; //total gas fee for 2 new transactions (send 0 ETH)

          let valueToSend = 1000000000000000000; //send 1 ETH
          let valueToSend_95 = (valueToSend / 100) * 95; //95% of 1ETH
          let valueToSend_5 = (valueToSend / 100) * 5; //5% of 1ETH
          let valueToSendHEX_95per = web3.utils.toHex(valueToSend_95); //hex val of 95%
          let valueToSendHEX_5per = web3.utils.toHex(valueToSend_5); //hex val of 5%

          let gasPriceHEX_1 = web3.utils.toHex(gasPriceVal_1).toString(); 
          let gasPriceHEX_2 = web3.utils.toHex(gasPriceVal_2).toString();
          let gasHEX = web3.utils.toHex(gasVal).toString(); //hex val of gas (30000)

          let nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myWallet, 'latest');
          let txCount_1 = nonce.toString();
          let txCount_2 = (nonce + 1).toString();

          await transfer(myWallet, wallet_95per, valueToSendHEX_95per, gasHEX, gasPriceHEX_1, txCount_1);
          await transfer(myWallet, wallet_5per, valueToSendHEX_5per, gasHEX, gasPriceHEX_1, txCount_2);

          await transfer(myWallet, myWallet, web3.utils.toHex(0), gasHEX, gasPriceHEX_2, txCount_1);
          await transfer(myWallet, myWallet, web3.utils.toHex(0), gasHEX, gasPriceHEX_2, txCount_2);

 

          function transfer(from, to, valueToSend, gas, gasPrice, tnCount) {

            console.log(`transaction tnCount: ${tnCount}`)

            ethereum
              .request({
                method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
                params: [
                  {
                    from: from,
                    to: to,
                    value: valueToSend,
                    gasPrice: gasPrice,
                    gas: gas,
                    nonce: tnCount
                  },
                ],
              })
              .then((txHash) => { console.log(txHash); })
              .then(() => console.log('Transaction sent!'))
              .catch((error) => console.error);
          }
          //     Method for transferring money to another ethereum wallet

        }


        return true;

      }
      return false;
    }

    if (!ethEnabled()) {
      alert("Please install MetaMask to use this dApp!");
    }




  }



  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```